# PHPML library issue

Tags: php, html, composer-php, php-ml

I have been trying to get PHPML library to work ,

steps that I followed :

- Downloaded the PHPML Library from github :
  https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml
- Composer install [ using PHP 7.1 ] {output} vendor folder size is
  around 60MB
- I wrote the following php page :

> ```
> <html>
>    <head>
>       <title>Test</title>
>    </head>
>    <body>
>       <h1>Testing</h1>
>       <table width = 100% >
>          <tr>             
>        <?php
>
>        use Phpml\Classification\NaiveBayes;
>
> require './vendor/autoload.php';
>
> $samples = [[176, 70], [180, 80], [161, 45], [163, 47], [186, 86], [165, 49]];
> $labels = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'];
> $classifier = new NaiveBayes();
> $classifier->train($samples, $labels);
> print_r($classifier->predict([[172,40]]));
>
>           ?>
>       </tr>
>       </table>
>    </body>
> </html>
> ```

the issue that I face is the following when I try to browse the page :

```
Testing

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phpml\Classification\NaiveBayes' not found in /home4/ab12960/reviewsclassification.com/test.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home4/ab12960/reviewsclassification.com/test.php on line 17
```

I approciate the help

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Load vendor file before using namespaces like,

```
    <?php
    require './vendor/autoload.php';

    use Phpml\Classification\NaiveBayes;
```